# Does it matter if I bought something on the wrong account?

Tags: ps4, the-division

I bought the season pass on the playstation store accidentally on my brothers user, I meant to purchase on my user. Does this even matter, or will it work on both users? How do I know if its even installed?

Answer (score 2):

Anything you buy will work for all users of the same PS4 as long as the user who purchased it has that PS4 set as their primary PS4.

To play a game on a given PS4, either:

- You must own the game on your own account, or
- Someone who has that PS4 as their primary PS4 must own the game on their account.

So long as you're sharing a PS4, this shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: I bought the disc from a shop and just bought the season pass online tonight is that a problem?

Comment: @max It's not a problem. You'll still need the disc in the PS4 to play in addition to the above.

Comment: so it wont work if his user isnt set as the primary ps4? Its my playstation thats all I dont want him to have control over anything?

Comment: @max Multiple users can set the same PS4 as their primary PS4. You're not picking the main account for the system; you're picking the main system for the account.

Comment: i understand! thankyou so much :)

Comment: I do have 1 more question, Im not sure if you are familiar with the game? But do you know how to check if this 'season pass' is installed?

Comment: @max I'm not familiar with The Division on PS4 in particular, so I don't know that. Sorry :(